# How to set product attribute in Magento programmatically?

Tags: php, magento

I have a Magento instance and I am using the following code:

```
include_once '../app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

try{

     $product_id = '';

     // get query string
     if (!isset($_GET['product_id'])) { $product_id = ''; } else { $product_id = $_GET['product_id']; }
     if (!isset($_GET['qty'])) { $qty = '1'; } else { $qty = $_GET['qty']; }

     $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);

     $session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));
     $cart = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart();

     $cart->addProduct($product, $qty);

     $session->setLastAddedProductId($product->getId());
     $session->setCartWasUpdated(true);

     $cart->save();

     $result = "{'result':'success'}";
     echo $result;

} catch (Exception $e) {
     $result = "{'result':'error'";
     $result .= ", 'message': '".$e->getMessage()."'}";
     echo $result;
}
```

However, I get an error that says 'Please specify the product required option(s).'
How do I set an attributes called "Colors" and default to "black" in the previous code?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add configurable to shopping cart you need to specify params for its attributes.
Data Example:

```
        [product] => 3
        [related_product] => 
        [super_attribute] => Array
            (
                [75] => 20
                [85] => 15
            )

        [qty] => 1
```

Here 75 - is "color" attribute_id, 20 -> 'option_id' of color "Black"
85 - is "Size" attribute_id, 15 -> option_id of size 'Big'.
So check in your database what is attribute_id of `Color` attribute and `option_id` of 'Black' color.

Comment: Thanks, Sergy! I was able to find the attribute ID I needed and it worked great.